Why does Finder search fail to find a word or number in filenames?
(Sequoia 15.2)
I have a list of PDF files in a Desktop folder all beginning with the word "Messages" and including a phone number. I want to search for files with a specific area code.
Here's a screenshot of the list with the unique part removed for privacy.

I enter area code 360 in the search box.

And select Name Contains "360".

"0 items" found despite there being several files with 360 in the filename.
I tried searching for "Messages" and got "4 items" instead of the many that one would expect. What's wrong?

You can force a reindexing of a folder by adding it to the Search Privacy list in the Spotlight settings panel, and then removing it.
